# TypedValue in Xamarin iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In android or xamarin droid there is a method `TypedValue.applyDimension` 
to [Converts an unpacked complex data value holding a dimension to its final floating point value](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)).
Is there any similar function like that in xamarin ios? or best approaches to do something like that

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, that kind of functionality doesn't exist on iOS out of the box. However, if you look at the actual Java implementation of that method, you'll notice it's quite simple:

```
public static float applyDimension(int unit, float value,
                                   DisplayMetrics metrics)
{
    switch (unit) {
    case COMPLEX_UNIT_PX:
        return value;
    case COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP:
        return value * metrics.density;
    case COMPLEX_UNIT_SP:
        return value * metrics.scaledDensity;
    case COMPLEX_UNIT_PT:
        return value * metrics.xdpi * (1.0f/72);
    case COMPLEX_UNIT_IN:
        return value * metrics.xdpi;
    case COMPLEX_UNIT_MM:
        return value * metrics.xdpi * (1.0f/25.4f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The values you get from the [DisplayMetrics](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Util.DisplayMetrics/) class should mostly be available in [UIScreen.MainScreen](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIScreen/) on iOS. Also, you might want to define the unit as an enumeration. That should be a good starting point for implementing your own calculations.